# Rest-Assured Get jsonPath when JSON key starts with number

Tags: rest-assured

How do i get name=status using json path ... problem here is key=2 is random number,,, is their any way to skip these random and read name

Am using rest assured ,,this is sample response on GET request

Response

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "2": {
            "name": "No Status",
            "protected": "1",
            "id": "1",
            "temporal_start": "0",
            "temporal_end": "2147483647"
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "Started",
            "protected": "1",
            "id": "2",
            "temporal_start": "0",
            "temporal_end": "2147483647"
        },
    }
}
```

my request code is

```
given()
   .param("error", "false")
   .when()
   .get(URI)
   .then()
   .body("data.2.name", startsWith(No))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution but it's not very elegant:

```
when().
       get(URI).
then().
       body("data.collect { it.value }.reverse()[0].name", equalTo("No Status")).
       body("data.collect { it.value }.reverse()[1].name", equalTo("Status"));
```

Which can be simplified using root paths:

```
when().
       get(URI).
then().
       root("data.collect { it.value }.reverse()[%d].name").
       body(withArgs("0"), equalTo("No Status")).
       body(withArgs("1"), equalTo("Status"));
```

Explanation:
Since data is a JsonObject represented as a HashMap we run the [collect](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)) method to return only the values of the Map as a List. Then we reverse the list since it seems like the last when running collect the resulting list will have the last value first. Then we get the first value from this list (data.2 in your example) and finally get the name.